# What type of mortar and trowel size be used for stacked stone around gas fireplace?

Tags: tile, mortar, stone, thinset

Specifically, I'm installing Rockmount Stacked Stone from MSI around a gas fireplace. Using 1/2" cement board as my backer.

https://www.msisurfaces.com/stacked-stone/silver-travertine/

I've already purchased a bag of Sturdi Flex TEC 345 from Menards. Was reading the instructions and it is not mentioning anything about using 1/2" x 1/2" x 1/2" trowels, but only mentions 1/4" and 3/8" size trowels.

https://www.tecspecialty.com/products/mortars-additives/sturdi-flex-thin-set-mortar/

Is this mortar acceptable or should I be using a different thinset?

Answer (score 2):

The mortar you purchased is for small to medium tile.

For small to medium tile a 1/4 to 3/8 notched trowel is what works best for proper setting.  1/2 " is too thick.

You have the correct thin set. Now get a 3/8" notched trowel ( my preference) or a 1/4".

A V-groove is too small.